# transfer searchview from actionbar to layout

Tags: android

hey guys i want to transfer my searchview from actionbar to inside of my android layout but when im transfering it ill get crashed. how to fix this problem? thanks for any help.

here is my logcat

```
04-12 19:57:28.277 25122-25122/com.example.lightning.myapplication3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.lightning.myapplication3, PID: 25122
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lightning.myapplication3/com.example.lightning.myapplication3.SetRouteActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                                                                                      at com.example.lightning.myapplication3.SetRouteActivity.onCreate(SetRouteActivity.java:53)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2537)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Comment: Your error is the your solution

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

You are using two separate versions of SearchView. Just stick to support.v7 one

Comment: from your logcat ->`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`   change your import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you receive is a `ClassCastException`
This means, the type you use is wrong.

```
searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.pointa);
```

You have two choices:

1) Look for the `import` statement of `SearchView` at the top of this class file and change it from `android.widget.SearchView` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` (or the other way round).

2) Take a close look at your XML file, looking for the `<SearchView` Tag. Is it possible, that because of the move, it changes from widget to support SearchView?

One of those two will fix your problem.
Hope this helps.